# Oracle SQL to find tables hierarchy in a schema

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, database-administration

I have a need to import some data for a given input from multiple table's and schema's based on a key.

For-Ex: I have ACCOUNT_ID COLUMN which is common to multiple tables (tables are interdependent with FK). I want to import data for a specific account from all the tables from multiple schema's and generate a SQL script.

But the challenge is, I need to identify parent table's first and then their child table's (tied with FK) in the order so that when I run the script, it shouldn't error out with integrity violation errors.

One way is to disable all the constraints, generate the script, run and then enable the constraints.

But I am trying to find if there's a better way of doing this. And enabling/disabling the constraints may not be a good solution for me.

Appreciate any inputs on this issue.

Comment: Check out this post:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/1051352?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

You say that your tables create a hierarchy based on foreign keys, so that for example T1 references T2, and T2 references T3 and so on.
In this case you need a hierarchical query.
First create a view that shows references between tables:

```
select c.table_name, uc.table_name as referenced_table_name 
from user_constraints c
join USER_CONS_columns uc ON c.r_constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
where c.constraint_type = 'R'
```

For example in this case:

```
CREATE TABLE ttt1(
   ACCOUNT_ID int primary key,
   somecolumn varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ttt21(
   id int primary key,
   ACCOUNT_ID int referencing ttt1( ACCOUNT_ID ),
   somecolumn varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ttt22(
   id int primary key,
   ACCOUNT_ID int referencing ttt1( ACCOUNT_ID ),
   somecolumn varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ttt211(
   id int primary key,
   ACCOUNT_ID int referencing ttt21( id ),
   somecolumn varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ttt2111(
   id int primary key,
   ACCOUNT_ID int referencing ttt211( id ),
   somecolumn varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ttt2112(
   id int primary key,
   ACCOUNT_ID int referencing ttt211( id ),
   somecolumn varchar2(100)
);
```

the view gives:

```
TABLE_NAME REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME   
---------- -------------------------
TTT22      TTT1                     
TTT211     TTT21                    
TTT21      TTT1                     
TTT2111    TTT211                   
TTT2112    TTT211
```

And now, with the help of this view, you can create a hierarchical query:

```
WITH my_view AS( 
    select c.table_name, uc.table_name as referenced_table_name 
    from user_constraints c
    join USER_CONS_columns uc ON c.r_constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
    where c.constraint_type = 'R'
) SELECT level, m.referenced_table_name  
FROM my_view m
START WITH referenced_table_name not in (select table_name from my_view )
CONNECT BY prior table_name = referenced_table_name;
```

which gives the following output:

```
     LEVEL REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME   
---------- -------------------------                    
         1 TTT1                     
         2 TTT21                    
         3 TTT211                   
         3 TTT211                   
         1 TTT1
```

A `LEVEL` column gives an order in which tables must be imported - first you need to process all tables at level 1, then at level 2 and so on and so on.